# Wireless icon disappeared on Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, 17.04, applet

Since I have been using the same wifi networks for the past few weeks its been no big deal that I dont have a wireless icon, but its odd that it suddenly disappeared out of nowhere.  What could have happened to it?

Did some of the commands; here is what I got, as the commands commentor 1 gave me didnt seem to work:

[Command line results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25673639/)

Here is the menu bar prior to entering sudo:

[image: panel showing no networking icon]

Comment: It's usual in Lubuntu. Just `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager` wait 5sec `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager` and  you will have it again. But you must inspect the cause. Post `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager` output, we will search for any "culprit".

Comment: I added to the questions of the result.

Comment: It's too hard to read output you post. Instead of that, post as text. You can [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) as this  text is a bit longer. Your problem may be lubuntu theme. Test with default theme to assure about this.

Comment: Here is the full code placed in pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25673639/  I tried to swap to lubuntu-default and that didn't seem to change anything.