# How to make LUbuntu connect to Wifi in an identical fashion to Live USB

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, dns

So I tried out LUbuntu 18.04 with a Live USB stick.  Everything worked great!  I could immediately see that there were WiFi networks, find my network, enter the passphrase and get connected.  But after I did a minimal install so I could fit it onto a 4GB USB flash drive, I discovered that WiFi was nowhere to be seen.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322861/how-to-connect-to-wireless-network-in-lubuntu) and tried `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`.  But nothing showed up even after running nm-applet.  I found [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html) and followed the steps to make it appear in the panel automatically, and the re-logged and it *still* didn't show up.

Then I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961329/wireless-icon-disappeared-on-lubuntu-17-04) and in a comment I found this:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager 
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

And that worked!  But when I tried to connect to my WiFi after entering the password it didn't do anything - no messages, or errors, or anything -  it just silently refused to connect!  Also, the appearance of this widget wasn't quite as slick as the one in the LiveUSB.

At some point I also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939674/lubuntu-17-04-will-not-connect-to-wifi-no-error-message-displayed) where I found and ran this command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I still couldn't get WiFi to work.  At some point I found someone suggest this:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

But when I tried to run the Wicd Network Manager I got the error describe at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366531/could-not-connect-to-wicds-d-bus-interface-check-the-wicd-log-for-error-messa).  I tried the answer which (modified to include all the necessary sudos) looked like this:

```
sudo service wicd stop
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo rm /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
sudo service wicd start
```

And now it connected to Wifi, although the interface was totally different from the LiveUSB, but... nothing would resolve on DNS.  Even when I plugged into wired Ethernet STILL nothing would work, it's like DNS suddenly broke!  The only way anything is working now is I manually edited /etc/resolv.conf (which was empty) and added:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

But I was reading somewhere that LUbuntu tries to run a DNS service of some kind on loopback (really? yech!) which makes me think that got broken somehow.  I really want to just get things to simply working the way they did in the Live USB.  What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a perfect solution while installed on an undersized USB flash drive - I went back and uninstall / purged wicd, and then re-installed network-manager-gnome, and at that point it started working better than before.  With a larger USB flash drive I would recommend just doing a full install, as then everything works "out of the box".

In general, the solution I ultimately went with was to get a larger SSD instead of using a USB flash drive and do the full install, as USB flash experiences frequent pauses whenever lots of random writes are happening which is an issue SSD does not have.